# How to update UI in blazor-server automatically every 2 seconds?

Tags: c#, blazor

Guys I am working with Blazor-Server, and now I am stuck at re-rendering and updating UI component automatically.

I did updates after mouse move to object, but I want full automatically.

This is UI component:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header" style="text-align:center;">Gate</div>
<div class="card-body">
<input @bind-value="@BinancePrice" @onmousemove="PriceCheck" />
```

This is my class:

```
private async Task PriceCheck()
{
    #region BinanceAPI
    try
    {
        using (_httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            _httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://testnet.binance.vision");
            _httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-MBX-APIKEY", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APIKEY"));
            _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("SecretKey", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SECRETKEY"));
            var symbol = "BTCBUSD";
            var market = new Market(_httpClient);
            var result = await market.CurrentAveragePrice(symbol);
            BinancePrice? binancePrice = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BinancePrice>(result);
            Lista["Binance"] = binancePrice!.Price.ToString();
            BinancePrice = binancePrice!.Price.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (BinanceClientException binanceException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(binanceException.InnerException?.Message ?? binanceException.Message);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: So you want to update your page every 2 seconds with new info from some service. You can use a System.Timer object (just google about it, I'm lazy). You can make and start one in the OnInitialized method.

Comment: As @T1Space said, pull the price periodically using an event on elapsed of timer with auto-reset https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=net-7.0

Comment: Try a (rather obvious) "blazor timer" search on here.

Comment: I will try this. Thanks guys i am brand new to Blazor, practicing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the UI to re-render automatically say every two seconds you can override the OnInitializedAsync() method in the razor page. See this for example:

This is the default Blazor server index with a paragraph added to show the current time:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<p>The current time is: @currentTime</p>

@code {
    private string currentTime = "";

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Set up a timer to update the current time every 2 seconds
        var timer = new System.Threading.Timer(
            e =>
            {
                InvokeAsync(() =>
                {
                    currentTime = DateTime.Now.ToString();
               
                    // Call this to force the server to send a new updated view
                    StateHasChanged();
                });
            },
            null,
            TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This works in localhost perfectly in the "infinite loop" but after i publish it to UBUNTU server it stops after 10seconds. Do you know why?

Comment: I'm struggling to replicate that issue. It could be something to do with your Ubuntu server maybe. I set a Blazor app running on Azure in a Linux environment with very little resources and don't seem to have the issue there.
https://matplinux.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: this is problem with responder. i fixed that. Your answer is correct