# How to close specific circuit in Blazor (server) app

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I monitor use of my application through `CircuitHandler`. It implements useful tasks like `OnCircuitOpened` or `OnCircuitClosed` but what I also want is to be able to force close certain circuits (a.k.a. kick users out). How can I do it in Blazor Server?

Comment: `kick users out`Do you mean you want to force user to sign out?Can you share your sample code?

Comment: No, not to sign out or any other fancy logic. Just close theirs circuit so they will see standard "Attempting to reconnect to the server: 1 of 8" message. I understand that they will hit refresh button and Blazor will get them a brand new circuit but that's fine.

Comment: Can you explain a little more why would you like to do this? can this link help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74814038/4444757